# Can Optaplanner take into account certain priorities when scheduling equipment?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm looking into Optaplanner as a way to schedule components being reserved by certain people at a given time. Certain users have certain priorities defined in my Spring Boot application which need to be taken into account when making reservations. E.g. A given user has priority over another user in reserving a specific component.

Can Optaplanner work around these additional constraints ?

Sorry if my question isn't super clear, I'm still working on fully understanding the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step you should probably list up your constraints clearly, as an exercise for yourself. This will result in a list of constraints of several categories. In your case, I think you'd end up with the categories Hard, Medium and Soft (the Medium category may be debatable). You could assign the constraint you're mentioning to the Medium category **or** to the Soft category : this depends on the context *you* consider most important...

If your (let me call it) "Employee asset reservation priority" constraint is so to say prevailing at all costs, you could assign that constraint to the Medium category.

On the other hand, if this "Employee asset reservation priority" constraint is not all too important, but "just one of the more important" constraints, you could give it a Soft category with a bigger weight than the other constraints in the Soft category.

It mainly depends on the (in)validity you consider a solution to have where a lower-reservation-priority employee runs off with the equipment a higher-reservation-priority employee had been trying to reserve...

(maybe this was a long explanation to confirm : yes, OptaPlanner can work around these constraints :-)